# How to find existing table in Mongo Atlas using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I already new several tables and save some data in those tables by Mongo Atlas. Now, I want to use Mongoose to search some data that I already saved from those tables. Do I need to write schemas and models for the tables that I already built by Mongo Atlas?

I've tried to write schemas and models using Mongoose, but it seems like it can not find the table that already in the Mongo Atlas. What should I do so that Mongoose can find the existed table and data in Mongo Atlas?

Comment: Can you show the code about how did you use Mongoose? Besides, make sure you are connecting the right database.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have existing tables and data in your MongoDB Atlas database, you don't necessarily need to define schemas and models for them in Mongoose.

Using the `mongoose.model()` function, You can create a model without specifying a schema, and Mongoose will use the existing collection in your MongoDB Atlas database.

Here's an example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

// Connect to your MongoDB Atlas database

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://URI', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

// Create a model without specifying a schema

```
const MyModel = mongoose.model('your existing collection', {}, 'name of the collection in your database');
```

// Perform queries on the existing collection

```
MyModel.find({}).then((data)=>{console.log(data)}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
```

Latest Mongoose does not accept call back.

You can then use the model to perform queries and other operations on your data.